# Moq and the parameters you pass

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I create a MOQ object

pass it to my class

call it and pass in an object.

How can I get access to this object to see if the right properties are set?

Comment: Are you passing the actual mock to your class or the mock.object?

Comment: This is what I want to do:
MyMock.MyMethod(MyObjectINeed);

How can I get MyObjectINeed?

Comment: Why don't you just keep a reference to it?  var myObj = myObjectINeed; MyMock.MyMethod(myObj); Assert.That(myObj) != null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly you seem to have a situation like this?

```
public void DoTheCalculation(ICalculator calculator) {
   calculator.Calculate(this /* Or any other object */);
}
```

In which case you can assert upon the arguments passed to a Mocked interface using the It.Is method that accepts a predicate:

```
[TestMethod]
public void DoTheCalculation_DoesWhateverItShouldDo() {
     Mock<ICalculator> calcMock = new Mock<ICalculator>();
     CalculationParameters params = new CalculationParmeters(1, 2);
     params.DoTheCalculation(calcMock.Object);

     calcMock.Verify(c => c.Calculate(It.Is<CalculationParameters>(
                         c => c.LeftHandSide == 1 
                              && c.RightHandSide == 2));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the `.VerifySet()` method on the mock object for this.  For instance

```
mockObject.VerifySet(o => o.Name = "NameSetInMyClass");
```

If it wasn't set properly, it will raise an exception.

Read more in the [quick start here](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is kind of confusing, it's unclear what object you're referring to in the last sentence.

However, every Moq wrapper has an "Object" property that is of the type that you are mocking.  You can access it by simply viewing that property.

```
var myMock = new Mock<MyObj>();

var myProp = myMock.Object.MyProperty;
```